# How to workaround gettext dependency problem when installing wine?

Tags: 12.10, wine, 64-bit, dependencies

```
$ LANG=C dpkg -l 'wine*'
dpkg-query: no packages found matching wine*

$ LANG=C dpkg -l 'ia32*'
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                              Version               Architecture          Description
+++-=================================-=====================-=====================-=======================================================================
un  ia32-apt-get                      <none>                                      (no description available)
ii  ia32-libs                         20090808ubuntu36      amd64                 ia32 shared libraries - transitional package
un  ia32-libs-gtk                     <none>                                      (no description available)
ii  ia32-libs-multiarch               20090808ubuntu36      i386                  Multi-arch versions of former ia32-libraries
un  ia32-libs-sdl                     <none>                                      (no description available)

$ grep wine /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-quantal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu quantal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-wine-ppa-quantal.list:deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu quantal main

$ LANG=C sudo aptitude -f install
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

$ LANG=C sudo aptitude install wine1.5-amd64
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  binfmt-support{a} fonts-droid{a} fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core{a} gettext:i386{ab} gettext-base:i386{ab} libasprintf0c2:i386{a} 
  libcapi20-3{a} libgif4:i386{a} libgomp1:i386{a} libnss-winbind{a} libodbc1{a} libosmesa6{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} libpam-winbind{a} libtiff4:i386{a} 
  ttf-droid{a} ttf-umefont{a} ttf-unfonts-core{a} unixodbc{a} unrar{a} winbind{a} wine-gecko1.8{a} wine-gecko1.8:i386{a} wine-mono0.0.8{a} wine1.5{a} 
  wine1.5-amd64 wine1.5-i386:i386{a} winetricks{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 29 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 165 MB of archives. After unpacking 474 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gettext-base : Conflicts: gettext-base:i386 but 0.18.1.1-9ubuntu1 is to be installed.
 gettext-base:i386 : Conflicts: gettext-base but 0.18.1.1-9ubuntu1 is installed.
 gettext : Conflicts: gettext:i386 but 0.18.1.1-9ubuntu1 is to be installed.
 gettext:i386 : Conflicts: gettext but 0.18.1.1-9ubuntu1 is installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     gettext:i386 [Not Installed]                       
2)     gettext-base:i386 [Not Installed]                  

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
3)     wine1.5-i386:i386 recommends gettext:i386
```

Comment: Can you tell us the context of this error ? What did you do/try ? What do you want to do ? The more you say the easier it is to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known [dependency problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gettext/+bug/954029).

Issue the following command to install `wine`:

```
sudo aptitude install wine1.5-amd64 gettext:i386-
```

The "-" after `gettext:i386` tells `aptitude` to remove (not install) that conflicting package.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that trick. Of course it helps.

Comment: Um krogon, I wouldn't suppose you could show Eric your gratitude by accepting his answer?